# "Xうわ"? What is X in image?

Tags: manga, symbols

Red enclosed area is the word include "X"

[image]

Comment: No, it's a [crown-like mark](https://ai-catcher.com/blog/2016/10/06/%E9%A9%9A%E3%81%8D/) to represent surprise. Same as the top-left one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"X" is not a glyph, it's a type of mark often used in *manga* in situations of surprise or similar reactions with some sudden emotional response. The same mark also appears above the woman on the left of the girl. (See also @broccoli's [link](https://ai-catcher.com/blog/2016/10/06/%E9%A9%9A%E3%81%8D/).)

The うわー written next to the little girl can also be used to convey surprise, like "wow!".